# Why are my pixels not aligning to grid in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixel, snapping

I have a small Problem that occurs from time to time.

Sometimes, when I copy things or when I put an object from the symbol library on my page, the whole file gets messed up. The screenshot shows it. I make the graphic on the right, Illustrator the ones on the left.

I have `pixel snapping` checked. **Is there a way to tell Illustrator to align everything to pixels no matter what?**

[image: pixel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make certain **Align to Pixel Grid** is checked in the Symbol Options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version you're using, but I've seen some unreliability with symbols aligning properly in versions CS5.5 and back. I've had to rebuild them from time to time to get the pixels back on track.

One thing that can cause problems is when type defines your symbol's upper or lower boundary. Fonts have some issues with obeying pixel boundaries. I often put an empty rectangle around type to create a clean edge.

Comment: Thank you. Thats interesting. An additional thing i used now was a script o align elements to Pixels which seems to be very helpful. + to find all the places where i have to check "align to pixel" and other tips. I will test that and i hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem that @plainclothes stumbled upon is to turn of the *align to pixel grid* within the symbol, but turn it on for the instance of the symbol that is placed on the canvas, by clicking on the x or y links on the info bar and enabling "align to pixel grid" just there. It basically means that your instance will snap to the pixel grid on the canvas, but there will be no interpolation within the symbol. Just try it and you will se how well it works.