# How to force Illustrator CS6 to work in whole pixels and fix fractional points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been using Illustrator to make a UI and as I learn how to use this software, the points of the shapes I made keep getting to fractions of a pixel. I have a great many points now and I'd rather not stop working every now and then to make sure every pixel is aligned to a whole value.

Is there a way to force Illustrator to only place points on whole values?
Is there a way to clean up existing points to round them to a whole value?

Comment: Relevant: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26803/why-are-my-pixels-not-aligning-to-grid-in-illustrator?rq=1 Turn on align to pixel grid.

Comment: It's been on. My pixels are still fractional.

Comment: Are you certain? You've selected objects then checked the Transform Panel?

Comment: You are thinking objects. I'm talking about individual points in objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your artboards don't sit on whole pixels, you might be using whole values but when you go to export, you'll have some fractional pixels.

The `CMD/CTRL` option @Dom mentioned doesn't work for me.

Go to `View>Snap To Grid`
[image]

Also make sure that your Grid preferences are set to your liking...

[image]

Also... I use the transform palette religiously because of this. [image]

Comment: You sir are amazing. Only solution that worked for me.

Comment: ;) Happy to help! I usually turn off `Align to Pixel Grid` as well. You'll see that above, at the bottom of the `Transform Palette` as well as at the bottom of the `New Document` dialog. Turning this off at the document level is a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Holding <kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd> while moving selected objects increments by whole pixels, however if your object starts on 22.94, it will jump to 23.94, so you have to begin on whole pixels.

Alternatively, if that only works in CC, you can set the keyboard increment to a specific amount in your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where anchors are snapped between pixels, you'll have to correct it's placement to whole-pixels in the top menu, OR, manually select and move individual anchors, and align them to the pixel grid, with the 'Direct Selection Tool' (Shortcut: 'A)'.